# Complex polynomial decomposition - Residue Theory

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, soft-question

I am given the following function: $R(z) = (z^2-9)/(z^2+9)^2 $

I need to let $R = P/Q$ be a rational function with $deg P < deg Q$. I will let $ξ$ be a pole of $R$ and the coefficient of $1/(z-ξ)$ in the partial fraction expansion of $R$ be the residue of $R(z)$ at $ξ$ (denoted $Res(ξ)$).

I need to find the decomposition of the above function $R(z)$ and then find the corresponding residues.

I don't know where to start. The reference books I have do not cover this section well at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write denominator as follows:$$\frac{z^2-9}{(z+3i)^2(z-3i)^2}$$
z=$-3i,+3i$ come to be two poles of order 2

$Res(3i)=\lim_{z\to 3i}\;\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^2-9}{(z+3i)^2}$
similarly residue at -3i can be found also

Comment: So then the only residue for this function is 3i then?

Comment: u can find residue at 3i,-3i as shown above

Comment: Can you tell me where you derived all parts to that formula you added?

Comment: in general, residue at pole of order n+1 is $lim_{z\to z_0}\;\frac{1}{n+1!}\frac{d^n}{dz}f(z)$